# Microsoft Keyboard shortcuts

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard, microsoft

I am using Microsoft Keyboard (With Ubuntu 12.04 KDE 64bit) and I have some keys there. For example Calculator key and start keys. I want start calculator as I press Calculator key and display Ubuntu start menu as I press Start key.
[image: http://plus4chan.org/b/tek/src/133955802652.jpg]

The output of `xev | grep key` for these keys is:

```
keys: 4294967265 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
state 0x10, keycode 104 (keysym 0xff8d, KP_Enter), same_screen YES, 
state 0x10, keycode 148 (keysym 0x1008ff1d, XF86Calculator), same_screen YES, 
state 0x10, keycode 148 (keysym 0x1008ff1d, XF86Calculator), same_screen YES,
state 0x10, keycode 148 (keysym 0x1008ff1d, XF86Calculator), same_screen YES,
state 0x10, keycode 148 (keysym 0x1008ff1d, XF86Calculator), same_screen YES,
```

Comment: If you run `xev | grep key` and then press these buttons, do you get any output?

Comment: I am getting  this output Seth. `xev | grep key 
keys:  4294967265 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0  

state 0x10, keycode 104 (keysym 0xff8d, KP_Enter), same_screen YES,

    state 0x10, keycode 148 (keysym 0x1008ff1d, XF86Calculator), same_screen YES,

    state 0x10, keycode 148 (keysym 0x1008ff1d, XF86Calculator), same_screen YES,
    state 0x10, keycode 148 (keysym 0x1008ff1d, XF86Calculator), same_screen YES,
    state 0x10, keycode 148 (keysym 0x1008ff1d, XF86Calculator), same_screen YES,`

Comment: Did you just press the calculator button 5 times? :P

Comment: Ian Carroll I pressed two time. One press return `keys: 4294967265 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
state 0x10, keycode 104 (keysym 0xff8d, KP_Enter), same_screen YES, 
state 0x10, keycode 148 (keysym 0x1008ff1d, XF86Calculator), same_screen YES, 
state 0x10, keycode 148 (keysym 0x1008ff1d, XF86Calculator), same_screen YES,`

Comment: That outa answer your question.